# cannot access excel file after renaming

Tags: excel, file, renaming

I have renamed some excel files on my web server and after renaming the users cannot download those files. What could be the problem. They are all excel files.

Comment: You're probably going to need to provide a bit more information than that.  What's an example of the "before" and "after" file names?  What web server are you using?  What kind of an error are the users getting?

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities I can think of:

- Make sure the extension on the files is still .xls (that's how it associates the mime type)
- Check the file protections on the files in case it, or the ownership got changed when you renamed them
- Make sure Excel didn't open them on the webserver (if a windows web server) as it will keep them locked until the EXCEL.EXE process is killed.

Might be one of those ...

Comment: Also, check that the case of the file is consistent with the links to that file. If you are using a *nix server, it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible problem is that your webserver is case-sensitive when it comes to file names, and when you renamed the files, the name might have different capitalisation to what it did before (think .XLS to .xls)

Answer (score 0):

One reason is renaming  file in webserver will requires refrseh or reloading the page.Did u try that

Answer (score 0):

I renamed an excel file from Columbus to Columbus PPWK by right clicking on the file name in the folder and scrolling to 'rename' and typing what I wanted. I have done this a trillion times with other files and no issues. When I tried to open this one, it would ask how do I want to open it with a bunch of options but nothing worked.  In addition the little picture next to the newly renamed file was just a blank white rectangle and not the normal white rectangle with the green X on it. I fixed it by simply renaming it to Columbus PPWK.xls  Once I added the .xls, it allowed me to open it again and I re-saved it to make sure it appeared and functioned normal, which it did.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to search some solution until I found it on my own. This may help. Renaming the file too long was the issue I encountered. Hence, make the file name short.